# Magento 2 tier price override

Tags: magento2, tierprice

By default, Magento will choose the price assigned to "ALL GROUPS" over the price assigned to a customer group if customer group's price is higher than ALL GROUPS price.

I want to override this logic and show the customer group's price even ALL GROUPS price is lower.

I just want to determine which class and method should I override for me to implement this. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Did you checked **vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/TierPrice.php** class?

```
/**
 * @param array $priceList
 * @return array
 */
protected function filterTierPrices(array $priceList)
{
    $qtyCache = [];
    $allCustomersGroupId = $this->groupManagement->getAllCustomersGroup()->getId();
    foreach ($priceList as $priceKey => &$price) {
        if ($price['price'] >= $this->priceInfo->getPrice(FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE)->getValue()) {
            unset($priceList[$priceKey]);
            continue;
        }

        if (isset($price['price_qty']) && $price['price_qty'] == 1) {
            unset($priceList[$priceKey]);
            continue;
        }
        /* filter price by customer group */
        if ($price['cust_group'] != $this->customerGroup &&
            $price['cust_group'] != $allCustomersGroupId) {
            unset($priceList[$priceKey]);
            continue;
        }
        /* select a lower price for each quantity */
        if (isset($qtyCache[$price['price_qty']])) {
            $priceQty = $qtyCache[$price['price_qty']];
            if ($this->isFirstPriceBetter($price['website_price'], $priceList[$priceQty]['website_price'])) {
                unset($priceList[$priceQty]);
                $qtyCache[$price['price_qty']] = $priceKey;
            } else {
                unset($priceList[$priceKey]);
            }
        } else {
            $qtyCache[$price['price_qty']] = $priceKey;
        }
    }
    return array_values($priceList);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sohel, this is indeed the method responsible for the tier price. I'm trying to intercept it through plugin but for some reason the plugin is not working.

<type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice">
        <plugin name="tier-price-intercepter" type="Zeald\GroupPrice\Plugin\Pricing\TierPrice" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>


Any idea why?

Comment: This is a protected method, so plugin not working. You need to create plugin for getTierPriceList method.